# Selenium is blocked when uploading a file

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Through selenium webdriver I'm attempting to automate a file upload (of large files consisting of hundreds of megabytes).

Usually it works fine, but sometimes the site doesn't upload the file and the upload progress gets stuck at 0%.

Therefore I'd like to check if the progressbar style.width is 0% after a certain interval of time (in order to determine if it's stuck).

Usually this would be no problem, however apparently Selenium is blocked when uploading a file (I assume it's because the request is in progress) and thus I get a timeout exception if I attempt to check the width before the upload has finished.

Do anyone know a way to solve this issue? IE. ignore the block in selenium to allow me to check the DOM without getting a timeout exception.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use Selenium for this, rather than a simple HTTP request, or `curl`, `scp`, `ssh`, FTP etc.?

Comment: @AndrewRegan
The thing is, the site is very JS centered so using raw HTTP requests is gonna prove to be very difficult if not impossible.

Comment: OK, so you're testing an upload feature of a site, not just trying to automate a manual admin task? In which case though, why the massive file? Does this work for small files?

Comment: @AndrewRegan
To be honest I'm not testing anything but automating an uploading task of an external website.

The thing is, when the uploading gets stuck at zero (which happens every now and then) I cannot run any driver methods until the request returns (which never happens) so I wonder if there is any way to bypass the "block" by selenium and actually check the page source.

Comment: Does the upload only block while running via Selenium, rather than manually? I don't see why Selenium should affect things if the real problem is a server error, JS error, or network issue. Maybe just a coincidence? Try to find out if any of those are the fundamental cause rather than trying to work around the problem with timeouts.

Comment: @AndrewRegan I think it's the way Selenium functions, that it always waits for the request to complete, no matter how long it takes. I found a similar thread who had the same issue as me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108482/selenium-findelement-blocks-until-file-upload-is-complete.

Yes the "real" problem is on the server side, but I have no control of it, thus I'm forced to detect when the issue occurs through Selenium.

It would easily be done if just Selenium didn't completely block throughout the request.

Comment: One quick and dirty way to defeat the blocking is to simply run the 'upload' click request in another thread and delay (`Thread.sleep()`) the main thread just long enough for the click to have happened. That's fine as long as the click thread never needs to interact with the main one. I've done this before to stop JavaScript queries blocking the mainline.

Comment: @AndrewRegan
Sorry for my late reply. I've read your comment 10 times but I still don't quite understand what you mean. Could you explain it in another way? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'WebDriverEventListener' class which has methods that can be used to
track file-uploading.